# Why don't they paint BB-8 to avoid being noticed at Maz's castle?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

The question "[Why do Han et al. go to Maz’s castle on Takodana?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112626/why-do-han-et-al-go-to-maz-s-castle-on-takodana)" has a good answer about ditching the Millennium Falcon because they know the First Order is looking for it in association with BB-8, Rey, and Finn.

But given that BB-8’s orange and white color scheme is described as unusual for a BB-unit by Poe Dameron, why don’t they paint him or something?

> He’s a BB unit. One of a kind. Orange and white. Utterly unique and
>   utterly invaluable.

Comment: Ermm... they didn't have any paint ?!

Comment: @RickSanchez as smugglers, i find that unlikely, and even still, why didn't they identify "make BB-8 less recognizable" as a goal in the stop at Maz's?

Comment: Poe says this BB unit is "one of a kind", was that what you meant?

Comment: Given the way BB-8 works, wouldn't painting her "gum up the works", i.e. render her immobile?

Comment: @MrLister maybe, but i thought i specifically remembered someone commenting on the orange being a recognizable trait. Did Poe mean visually, or just that BB-8 held unique information?

Comment: @Martha probably. I'm still surprised nobody suggests disguise.

Comment: @RobStarling - Poe. "“He’s a BB unit. One of a kind. Orange and white. Utterly unique and utterly invaluable.”

Comment: @DVK so not a sign either way. thanks! (think i should just remove it from the question?)

Comment: Why is this downvoted???

Comment: @JakeGould Don't we see various instances of machines spray-painting droids and robots two whole generations earlier, and that paint seemingly drying on the spot? In a universe as technologically advanced as the Star Wars universe, I doubt they'd have to sit around with brushes, painting BB-8 manually and waiting hours for it to dry.

Comment: @RobStarling Maybe a hat ? ( disguise )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no direct canon answer (novelization or Visual Dictionary), but it's strongly implied that it didn't matter:

- Han knew that Millennium Falcon was likely tracked, so Bad Guys would know they are on Takodana **anyway**, being recognized or not.

  > “Why are we here again?” he asked as they started up a wide, curving stone staircase.
  >   “**To get your droid on a clean ship. Do you think it was luck that Chewie and I found the Falcon? If we can find it on our scanners, the First Order’s not far behind**.” Han indicated the soaring walls now rising before them. Colored flags representing numerous cultures and tribes hung from the battlements, some banners more faded and frayed than others. “The galaxy’s full of watering holes, but nothing like this place. It’s been run by an old smuggler named Maz Kanata for a thousand years. Want to get Beebee-Ate to the Resistance? Maz is our best bet.” *(Alan Dean Foster's Novelization)*
- Han only planned to be on Takodana for a short while, get a new, clean ship from Maz, and haul tail out of there ASAP.

Comment: This seems right to me.  BB-8 or no BB-8, now everyone in the universe knows they're looking for Han Solo and Chewbacca in the Millennium Falcon, thanks to the Scottish guy on Han's cargo ship.  It's basically a race against the clock to find some incognito transportation.

Comment: @paultamalunas - but **in-universe**, Han didn't know that the gangster made that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Speculation questions like this have no definite answer.  They could have put BB-8 in a box or just left him on the Falcon.  Really anything attempt to disguise themselves would have prevented a lot of problems, but would have prevented the story from developing.

Comment: True (and i'm not this answer's downvote, btw). Would it be interesting to ask if there's any mention of an in-universe reason that droids could or could not be painted in general? (i seem to recall Luke's squadrons' droids matching either their helmets or their x-wings)

Comment: ^ for this, there's this answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/20129/58214