# What are the standard, stock color schemes available for an “off-the-shelf” BB unit droid?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, droids

Saw [this quote from Poe Dameron in this question regarding BB-8](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112670/14850):

> He’s a BB unit. One of a kind. Orange and white. Utterly unique and
>   utterly invaluable.

So, if BB-8 has some “utterly unique and utterly invaluable” orange and white paint job compared to other droids—I mean Poe’s [“Black One” X-Wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Black_One) is a custom all black job as well—then what’s the color scheme of a standard, stock, “off the shelf” BB unit?

Comment: I don't think shelves make very good storing places for droids that are completely round. ;-)

Comment: better off storing them on the things you keep bowling balls @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: Couldn't the "utterly unique" part be about his *personality*, not his coloring?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [MakingStarWars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/BB_unit), BB units come in a *variety* of colours. The Resistance has some older models in metallic tints and the First Order's ones come in black and red.

> *On a side note, there are Resistance BB units in the film too.
> However, these guys look very rusty and old. They are not evocative of
> Artoo-Detoo like BB-8 is. I want to say they’re almost steam punk in
> design. Their look is very brassy and beat up and they’re in contrast
> to the First Order BB units that are black with red hot vents on the
> side of the body. It all makes BB-8 all the more unique. However, it
> appears BB-8 will be with Finn and “Rose” for the majority of the
> film. We still aren’t sure if Poe will fly with one of the new brass
> Resistance BB droids or if BB-8 will return in time for a reunion
> flight with Poe.*
>
> <sub><sup>[LAURA DERN, POE DAMERON, & THE DROIDS OF THE RESISTANCE IN STAR WARS: THE LAST JEDI.](http://makingstarwars.net/2017/04/laura-dern-poe-dameron-the-droids-of-the-resistance-in-star-wars-the-last-jedi/)</sup></sub>

---

**Licensed (bobble-head) version and Sphero Version.**

[image] [image]
<sub>*Note the square headpiece.*</sub>

**(Unpainted) Resistance BB Units**

[image]

The *[Star Wars: Droidography](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Droidography)* (in-universe) factbook shows us a wide variety of BB units, available in a range of different colours.

[image]

---

<s>**We don't know (yet).**</s>

There are no other [BB-units](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/BB_unit) seen anywhere else within the Star Wars canon, nor in any of the [concept arts](http://www.blastr.com/2015-12-28/star-wars-force-awakens-concept-art-reveals-early-designs-bb-8) that have been released. It's not detailed in either of the novelisations (Junior / Official), nor are any of the X-wings in the film using BB-units as their astromechs.

Comment: How about doing something like [this](http://photodoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/6-pop-art.jpg) for the image? :D

Comment: Should note that the bobble-head is a BB-9E, and Empire droid (dubbed "BB-8's evil twin").

Comment: Also see this 3D model supposedly made for the toy by Sphero: https://www.artstation.com/artwork/m4P21